# Email notifications not working (never)

Tags: support, email-notification

I know it has been asked before but I never receive notifications, even after weeks. I suppose setting it in my account settngs should be enough, isn't it?

> [image]

**EDIT**

I don't think it's a duplicate because in my case I don't click on inbox for weeks, or even access stackexchange for such periods, nevertheless I don't get notified of messages (that I only see when I get back to stackexchange)

Comment: It says "unread inbox items", so if you open the inbox, no matter on which site, all items are marked "read" thus won't be sent to your email.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136722/162102

Comment: In my case I don't receive notifications even if I stay away from stackexchange for weeks. When I get back I see that my inbox has messages from a week or two before. That shouldn't happen right?

Comment: Maybe it reach the spam folder, maybe you have some filters blocking emails not in a whitelist. Make sure to add the domain stackexchange.com to the Safe Senders list, or whatever you got on your side for this.

Comment: @giohappy you don't seem to be getting [much activity in your inbox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7HRJs.png). I checked our email logs, and the last inbox notification you received was back in 2013 for the comments on [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/41082).

Comment: @giohappy also, if you mean notification about the +30 reputation, we don't get notification for rep changes, only for inbox items